# AC, when outside temperature is lower than the operating temperature

Tags: thermodynamics

> Suppose the outside temperature is $-20^{\circ}C$ and a person is in a room of his house operating his air conditioner at $20^{\circ}C$

Will he feel colder or hotter or he won't feel any change in the temperature he perceives compared to the outside temperature$?$

---

My logic says that if the outside temperature is $-20$ and AC is maintaing the room at $20$ the of course he should feel hotter, but somehow I cannot digest this fact. How can an AC do the job of heating $?$ My intuition is saying that he should feel colder.

Please guide me with the correct reasoning.

Comment: "Will he feel colder or hotter or he won't feel any change in the temperature he perceives compared to the outside temperature?" What he will likely feel is the pain of an AC repair bill.

Comment: That's a good one, @BobD.  Hahahaha!

Comment: Heat pumps are a thing (not just ac, but ac and heat).

Comment: My home has a machine that I call "AC," and it is controlled by a _thermostat._ If I set the thermostat to 20C when the indoor temperature is 20C and the outdoor temperature is much less than 20C, then the thermostat will never turn the machine on. The thermostat only turns the machine on when the indoor temperature rises above the set point, which will.not happen when the outdoor temperature is so much colder.

Comment: (My home's "AC" has only one function. It removes heat from the house when it is running, and it does nothing otherwise.)

Answer (score 0):

A person would feel warmer in a 20C room than outside on a -20C day.

> ...and AC is maintaing the room at 20...

The statement you started with says nothing about the AC maintaining 20C, just that the AC is running and the current temperature of the room is 20C.

If the AC runs for a period of time, the temperature inside should drop.